# Bash autocomplete gives different file name than ls

Tags: bash, filesystems, ls, filenames, autocomplete

An incredibly strange thing just happened. Through a serious typo, I entered

```
cp filename.xsl .^?~
```

Yeah, that's right, dot-caret-questionmark-tilde! Truth is stranger than fiction.

It gets weirder. When I type

```
cat .
```

and then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I get

```
./    ../    .^?~
```

but when I do an `ls -a`, I get

```
.    ..    .?~
```

Finally, when I do

```
rm .?~
```

the remove command prompts me thus:

```
rm: remove write-protected regular file `.\177~'?
```

before successfully removing it.
Why the descrepency of the existence of the caret?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because the caret is often used to signify the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key having been pressed, or that it's otherwise a control character.

The key sequence that you actually typed was this:

`cp filename.xsl .`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You were presumably trying to copy the file to your home directory (`~`). You can repeat this by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd>. You'll see `^?` printed on the screen.

You can view files with non-printing characters converted to **C-style** escapes like this (it's the `-b` flag that's important, but since your file begins with a dot you'll need `-a` as well:

```
$ ls -ab
.  ..  .\177~
```

Without the `-b` you only see it as `.?~` not because it's simply omitting the `^`, but because any non-pritable character is displayed as `?`. Try `touch`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>foo</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and then `ls`. The file you'll see will be `?foo`. Then `ls -b` will show `\rfoo`.

So when you `rm .?~` it is matching because in this case the `?` you typed is interpreted by the shell as a globbing wildcard to match any single character, not specifically an actual question mark. You have `rm` aliased to `rm -i` so it's confirming your action and when it does it shows the C-style escape code.

Comment: Wow! Yes, I was trying to copy it to my home directory... I'm shocked you figured that out given how many extra keys I hit! The other answers were good, but this is excellent. +1

Answer (score 2):

The strange character you have in that filename (as indicated by `rm`) is character `0177` (`0x7F`<sub>h</sub>/`127`<sub>d</sub>). That's the `Del` character.

Bash autocompletion seems to be failing to handle it consistently.
`ls` prints a `?` for unprintable characters (by default). Try:

```
$ echo a > .$'\x7f'~
$ ls -b .??
.\177~
```

`rm` is being helpful and prints its octal value.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit TAB, and the shell does some kind of filename guessing, it's printing two characters, '^' and '?' for the byte valued octal 177.  You can get a filename with a byte of that value by hitting ctrl-V then shift-ctrl-? (three keys at once) for testing.

The file name wasn't dot-caret-questionmark-tilde, but rather dot-octal 177-tilde. Different programs chose to represent the octal-177 valued byte different ways.